# How do I change the default location for the desktop?

Tags: 13.04, .desktop

I want to change the location of my desktop so if I save a file to the desktop it will save to a folder in my other hard drive

Comment: A little context would help. Why do you want to do this? Would directory link on your desktop do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

In `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` you can change the location of your Desktop folder. If you want to set your desktop to be located at, for example, `/media/my-other-hardrive` you can change the line:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

to

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="/media/my-other-hardrive"
```